# Adicionar rownames como coluna usando dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Eu gostaria de fazer algo que é bastante simples usando a sintaxe comum do R, mas usando o pacote `dplyr`.

A tarefa é basicamente adicionar os `row.names` de um objeto `data.frame` como coluna nesse mesmo objeto. Usando `mtcars` como exemplo, isso poderia ser feito assim:

```
dados <- mtcars
dados$nomes <- row.names(mtcars)
```

Eu gostaria de fazer algo do tipo

```
dados <- mtcars %>% mutate(nomes=row.names(.))
```

Mas esse código dá o erro `Error: unsupported type for column 'nomes' (NILSXP)` (claro, pois estou fazendo algo errado).

Gostaria de saber se existe um jeito de resolver esse "problema".

Comment: Boa pergunta! Também gostaria de saber.

Comment: +1 muito boa pergunta.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## ***Atenção***: update no magrittr 1.5

A partir do [magrittr 1.5](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/12/01/magrittr-1-5/), o ponto (.) do operador `%>%` funciona com chamadas aninhadas. Dessa forma, ele substitui corretamente o ponto dentro de `row.names(.)` e agora o exemplo funciona normalmente sem qualquer modificação.

```
dados <- mtcars %>% mutate(nomes=row.names(.))
head(dados)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb             nomes
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4         Mazda RX4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     Mazda RX4 Wag
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1        Datsun 710
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    Hornet 4 Drive
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet Sportabout
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1           Valiant
```

---

***Resposta dada antes do magrittr 1.5***

Complementando a resposta do Rogério.

### O que o `%>%` está fazendo?

Se você pegar o código do `%>%`, grosso modo, ele cria um novo ambiente e joga o que está no lado esquerdo neste ambiente. Depois pega o comando que está no lado direito, modifica algumas coisas, e manda executar o comando modificado dentro deste novo ambiente.

Por exemplo, se você rodar `mtcars %>% mutate(., nomes = row.names(.))`, o lado esquerdo é `mtcars` e o lado direito é `mutate(., nomes = row.names(.))`:

```
lhs <- substitute(mtcars)
rhs <- substitute(mutate(., nomes = row.names(.)))
```

Cria-se um novo ambiente e um nome para o lado esquerdo:

```
env <- new.env(parent = parent.frame())
nm <- paste(deparse(lhs), collapse = "")
```

Salva-se o lado esquerdo no novo ambiente com o nome criado:

```
env[[nm]] <- eval(lhs, env)

#Para ver que o objeto foi criado:
head(env$mtcars)
```

Agora é preciso trocar os pontos do comando do lado direito. A parte que identifica onde os pontos estão é:

```
dots <- c(FALSE, vapply(rhs[-1], identical, quote(.), 
                              FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
```

Mas note que ela percorre apenas o primeiro nível da chamada.

```
dots
            nomes 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Na hora de substituir, portanto, apenas o primeiro ponto é substituído:

```
 rhs[dots] <- rep(list(as.name(nm)), sum(dots))
 e <- rhs
 e
 # veja que apenas o primeiro ponto foi substituído
 mutate(mtcars, nomes = row.names(.))
```

Assim, quando você executa a função no ambiente env, como não existe um objeto chamado ".", ocorrerá o erro:

```
eval(e, env)
Erro em row.names(.) : objeto '.' não encontrado
```

A solução para isso seria que a parte de substituição ocorresse em todos os níveis da chamada. Por exemplo, se mudarmos o outro ponto de `e` manualmente:

```
e[[3]][[2]] <- as.name("mtcars")
```

Agora funciona:

```
eval(e, env)
# resultado omitido porque é grande
```

### Por que funcionou com o `%.%` colocando `'_prev'`?

A função por trás do `%.%` é `chain_q`. Para ver o código, digite `dplyr:::chain_q`.

```
function (calls, env = parent.frame()) 
{
    if (length(calls) == 0) 
        return()
    if (length(calls) == 1) 
        return(eval(calls[[1]], env))
    e <- new.env(parent = env)
    e$`__prev` <- eval(calls[[1]], env)
    for (call in calls[-1]) {
        new_call <- as.call(c(call[[1]], quote(`__prev`), as.list(call[-1])))
        e$`__prev` <- eval(new_call, e)
    }
    e$`__prev`
}
```

Note que a função cria um novo ambiente chamado `e` e guarda a primeira chamada da cadeia de comandos com o nome `'_prev'` (`e$'__prev' <- eval(calls[[1]], env)`. Por isso que você consegue acessar o resultado do comando anterior dessa forma.

### Hackeando o %>% (apenas para ilustração)

Se montarmos uma função que troca todos os pontos, como essa ([baseada nesta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154252/easily-finding-and-replacing-every-match-in-a-nested-list)):

```
convert.call <- function(x, replacement) {
  if (is.call(x)) as.call(lapply(x, convert.call, replacement=replacement)) else
    if (identical(x, quote(.))) as.name(replacement) else
      x
}
# testando
expr <- substitute(mean(exp(sqrt(.)), .))
convert.call(expr, "x")
# mean(exp(sqrt(x)), x)
```

Aí podemos hackear a definição de `%>%` para fazer com que todos os pontos sejam trocados:

```
`%>%` <- function (lhs, rhs) 
{
  convert.call <- function(x, replacement) {
    if (is.call(x)) as.call(lapply(x, convert.call, replacement=replacement)) else
      if (identical(x, quote(.))) as.name(replacement) else
        x
  }
  
  lhs <- substitute(lhs)
  rhs <- substitute(rhs)
  if (is.call(rhs) && identical(rhs[[1]], quote(`(`))) 
    rhs <- eval(rhs, parent.frame(), parent.frame())
  if (!any(is.symbol(rhs), is.call(rhs), is.function(rhs))) 
    stop("RHS should be a symbol, a call, or a function.")
  env <- new.env(parent = parent.frame())
  nm <- paste(deparse(lhs), collapse = "")
  nm <- if (nchar(nm) < 9900 && (is.call(lhs) || is.name(lhs))) 
    nm
  else "__LHS"
  env[[nm]] <- eval(lhs, env)
  if (is.function(rhs)) {
    res <- withVisible(rhs(env[[nm]]))
  }
  else if (is.call(rhs) && deparse(rhs[[1]]) == "function") {
    res <- withVisible(eval(rhs, parent.frame(), parent.frame())(eval(lhs, 
                                                                      parent.frame(), parent.frame())))
  }
  else {
    if (is.symbol(rhs)) {
      if (!exists(deparse(rhs), parent.frame(), mode = "function")) 
        stop("RHS appears to be a function name, but it cannot be found.")
      e <- call(as.character(rhs), as.name(nm))
    }
    else {
      e <- convert.call(rhs, nm)
    }
    res <- withVisible(eval(e, env))
  }
  if (res$visible) 
    res$value
  else invisible(res$value)
}
```

Veja que agora `mtcars %>% mutate(., nomes = row.names(.))` funciona. Mas coloquei isso aqui apenas para explicar o que está acontecendo, não recomendaria você utilizar a versão hackeada do `%>%` pois pode ser que ocasione bugs em outras ocasiões --- por exemplo, da forma que está você explicitamente vai ter que colocar os pontos toda hora, como em `mtcars %>% filter(., cyl==4) %>% mutate(., nomes = row.names(.))`.

### dplyr não necessariamente mantém row.names nas operações

Uma última nota: o dplyr (nem o data.table) não mantém intactos os row.names durante operações. Repare que o dplyr substitui o row.names no `filter` e o data.table substitui já quando que você converte o data.frame:

```
mt_dplyr <- filter(mtcars, cyl==4)
row.names(mt_dplyr)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11"

mt_dt <- data.table(mtcars)
row.names(mt_dt)
1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22"
[23] "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31" "32"
```

Assim, no fim das contas, se o row.names contém informação relevante, parece ser mais seguro transformá-lo em uma coluna antes de manipular mais os dados.

### Uma "solução" alternativa: criando sua própria função mutate que tem um `row_names` local

Uma solução que pode ser feita é a seguinte: você cria o seu próprio mutate que guarda um vetor `row_names` dentro de seu ambiente pai (que no contexto será o ambiente de `%>%`, mas se você usar a função sozinha será o ambiente global, então cuidado) e depois executa o mutate do dplyr neste ambiente. Assim, se você quiser usar os nomes das linhas, basta utilizar o objeto `row_names`. Vamos chamar nosso `mutate` de `mutate2`:

```
mutate2 <- function(x, ...){
  assign("row_names", row.names(x), parent.frame())
  eval(substitute(mutate(x, ...)), parent.frame())
}

mtcars %>% mutate2(z = cyl^2, nomes=row_names) %>% filter(z==36)

   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  z          nomes
1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 36      Mazda RX4
2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 36  Mazda RX4 Wag
3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 36 Hornet 4 Drive
4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 36        Valiant
5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 36       Merc 280
6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 36      Merc 280C
7 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 36   Ferrari Dino
```

Comment: Vc quis dizer q não dá pra colocar rownames em coluna do df apenas com o %>% ?

Comment: @Athos, isso, da forma como está o pacote o comando `mutate(., nomes = row.names(.))` não funcionará porque o segundo ponto não é substituído, e não consigo imaginar uma forma simples resolver isso.

Comment: Comentários fantásticos! Obrigado!

Comment: @JulioTrecenti adicionei uma alternativa, criando o seu próprio mutate2 que tem um vetor de row.names caso você precise utilizar

Comment: Super elegante! Tks

Comment: @JulioTrecenti havia um bug na função, agora está corrigido.

Answer (score 8):

Julio,

Não consegui pensar numa solução usando o `dplyr`, mas uma solução simples e que talvez deixe o código mais limpo é, criar uma função `row_names`da seguinte forma:

```
row_names <- function(x, var){
  var <- deparse(substitute(var))
  x[var] <- row.names(x)
  return(x)
}
```

Depois você pode usá-la assim:

```
mtcars %>% row_names(nomes) %>% filter(cyl == 6)
```

Talvez assim a eficiência do `dplyr` seja perdida, mas fica bonitinho..

**Edit:**

É possível escrever uma função que faz algo similar à primeira solução do Rogério, usando o `dplyr`

```
row_names_d <- function(x, var){
  var <- deparse(substitute(var))
  x <- mutate(x, rn = row.names(x))
  names(x)[length(names(x))] <- var
  return(x)
}

mtcars %>% row_names_d(nome)
```

Mas fiz o benchmark e não parece que vale a pena...

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
+   
+   mtcars %>% row_names(nome),
+   mtcars %>% row_names_d(nome)
+   
+   
+   )
# Unit: microseconds
#                         expr     min       lq   median      uq     max neval
#   mtcars %>% row_names(nome) 183.334 194.0015 202.4965 210.399 326.760   100
# mtcars %>% row_names_d(nome) 244.972 259.5905 268.4810 279.149 551.581   100
```

Comment: Muito bom, Daniel! Vou aceitar essa como resposta pois é de fato uma solução. Recomendo que todos olhem a resposta do Rogério e do Carlos, pois mostram uma solução alternativa e uma aula de R, respectivamente.

Comment: + 1 bacana Daniel

Comment: Só um comentário: as respostas aqui do SOpt estão ficando bem legais, a comunidade está crescendo!

Answer (score 5):

Tente isso aqui:

```
    library(dplyr)
    dados <- mtcars
    dados %>% mutate(names = row.names(dados))
```

Você também pode fazer:

```
    dados %.% mutate(names = row.names(`__prev`))
```

`__prev` (entre crases) indica o elemento anterior (previous) da cadeia. E esse argumento só funciona quando vc substitui %>% por %.%

Veja também esse post no SO-en:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621209/differences-between-dplyr-and-magrittr

Comment: Obrigado! o `%.%` com \`__prev\` ajuda. A outra solução não resolve exatamente meu problema, pois eu queria justamente "evitar" usar o df anterior como argumento, fazendo duas atribuições. Por exemplo, não teria como fazer se eu quisesse `dados %>% filter(cyl==2) %>% mutate(names=row.names(dados))`, a menos que eu guardasse o bd filtrado em outra variável, e eu não queria isso.

Answer (score 4):

Existe uma função chamada `rownames_to_column` do pacote `tibble` que permite fazer isso:

```
mtcars %>% rownames_to_column()
```